# How do I access the program name / argv[0] in Forth?

Tags: forth, gforth

The [Gforth documentation](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/OS-command-line-arguments.html) say to access arguments by calling `next-arg`, but this omits the program name, which would be printed in a C-like language.

Since `argv[0]` seems to be automatically removed from the argument vector in Forth, is there a special function I can call that does return it?

Comment: `argc` & `argv` might be of help here. The [manual](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/OS-command-line-arguments.html#index-argc-_0040var_007b-_002d_002d-addr---_007d--gforth-2242) states those words account for the command name too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sourcefilename` gives the program's name, and `n arg` gets the arguments that were sent to gforth, including the gforth binary name.

Comment: Aww, how could I miss `arg` while reading the same page? Just incredible. Great finds, +1.

Comment: Yeah, I had to sign up for the gforth mailing list to find this stuff out.

Answer (score 1):

`0 arg` will always return `argv[0]`, while the rest of the arg list is modified by `next-arg`. `sourcefilename` is the name of the file you are just loading.